# Is there an Exchange Powershell command that allows events to be added to room resources in OWA?

Tags: exchange, powershell, outlook, outlook-web-app

We have an onsite Exchange server, we have a room resource that has been created and is opened as an other calendar in Outlook. When using Outlook 2007 we can add an event to the resource. When we log into the OWA we can see the event, and the calendar. However, when we try to add an event to the resource via OWA, the calendar is unavailable to select.
You can see in the screenshot below the issue. testresource is listed in Other Calendars along with Radio, however it is not available in the calendar: drop down menu when trying to create a new event.

What is the Exchange Powershell command that will make other calendars available from New Event in the OWA?

[image]

---

edit: Permissions are identical between radio and testresource (testresource has even had the administrator added to full access.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OWA, normal invitations should not involve you picking the Calendar in the interface.  You only have this permission in OWA because you have FullAccess to the entity assigned in Exchange, and that's now how bookable resources are designed to work.

Normally when scheduling resources, you would instead set the Location as a Room from the Room List or invite the Resource as a invitee.

I'm in office 365, and Equipment shows up under either the All or People views, but Rooms show properly in the Room List.

You should be sending an invitation to the calendar, then Exchange Calendar Processing accepts or rejects the request based on set policy.  You're trying to bypass this by putting meetings directly on the calendar of the resource/room.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a permissions issue. I added screenshot of the permissions settings for both resources. Domain Users have full access to both resources. I tested your idea about adding the resource as an invitee, it does add the event, but it's can't be edited from the resource calendar from OWA.